# How to print HttpRequest headers in angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new to angular so here is the situation: There is a back-end application which is sending some header information to the front end application which is on Angular 5, so i need to fetch those header information at my landing page.
I am using interceptors here is the code

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log('Before sending data');
     console.log('Request : ', req);
     console.log('Headers are');
     console.log('USER: ' + req.headers.get('USER'));
```

Please suggest any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

have you expose the x-token from server side? using "access-control-expose-headers". because not all headers are allowed to be accessed from the client side, you need to expose them from the server side

also in your frontend, you can use new HTTP module to get a full response using {observe: 'response'} like

```
http
  .get<any>('url', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Token'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read your response headers directly in your `interceptor`

Try something like this

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap((event) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log(event.headers);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Make sure you are exposing your headers from he response `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

Hope this helps - Happy coding :)